# Stored procedure to get the last name, department number, and department name for all employees

Tags: sql, oracle

In the compartment I need to write a stored procedure that retrieves the last name, department number, and part name for all employees. The data needs to be output to the cursor to print to the screen. What's wrong with this statement?

```
create   or REPLACE procedure getempldept(
 ed_emplid in employees.last_name%type,
 ed_deptid in  employees.department_id%type,
 ed_deptname in departments.department_name%type
)
 is 
begin
 select last_name,department_id,department_name into ed_emplid,ed_deptid,ed_deptname
 from employees,departments
  where department_id=ed_deptid;
 commit;
end;
```

Use the stored procedure to print to the screen the last name and hire date for all employees who were hired in 1994 with input parameter of year

```
create or REPLACE PROCEDURE  empl_get (
    g_Emp  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
begin
OPEN g_Emp FOR
 select last_name, hire_date  from employees 
 where TO_CHAR(employees.hire_date,'yyyy')>='2003';
 end ;
```

Comment: I see several things wrong.  But the first question is what are _you_ seeing?  Error messages when you run the CREATE statement?  Errors when you actually execute the procedure that is created by the CREATE statement?  What do you find when you google the error messages?  I could give you corrected code as an answer, but first you need to show a little initiative here.

Comment: I don't understand what the mistake is, can you explain it

Comment: First, too_many_values exception if you query fetch multiple rows, why are you passing parameters in the first procedure and even if you are passing they are in IN mode and you are using them for assignment.

Comment: 'create   or REPLACE procedure getempldept(
 ed_emplname in employees.last_name%type,
 ed_deptid in  employees.department_id%type,
 ed_deptname in departments.department_name%type
)
 is 
begin
 for empldeft in getempldept loop 
 select empldeft.ed_emplname,empldeft.ed_deptid,empldeft.ed_deptname
 from employees,departments
  where department_id=ed_deptid;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Employename: '|| empldeft.ed_emplname , ' departname:' ||empldeft.ed_deptid , 'departid :' || empldeft.ed_deptname );
  end loop
 commit;
end;  ' This is what you mean

Comment: _"I don't understand what the mistake is, can you explain it"_   Help us to help you.  When you are asked a question, answer it. I repeat my questions.  what output do you see when you run the CREATE statement?  what output do you see when you actually execute the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after formatting your revised code that you put into a comment, we see

```
 CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Getempldept( ed_emplname IN employees.last_name%TYPE,
                                        ed_deptid    IN employees.department_id%TYPE,
                                        ed_deptname  IN departments.department_name%TYPE )
IS
BEGIN
  FOR empldeft IN getempldept
  LOOP
    SELECT empldeft.ed_emplname,
           empldeft.ed_deptid,
           empldeft.ed_deptname
    FROM   employees,
           departments
    WHERE  department_id=ed_deptid;
    
    dbms_output.Put_line ('Employename: '
    || empldeft.ed_emplname , ' departname:'
    ||empldeft.ed_deptid , 'departid :'
    || empldeft.ed_deptname );
  END LOOP COMMIT;
END;
```

So let me ask you this:  You have input parameters to provide a single employee id, a single department name, and a single departement Id. If your task is "retrieves the last name, department number, and part name for all employees." then what are you going to achieve with your input parameters?  Remember, you said "*all* employees".  If what you really want is all employees _in a given department, then you'd only need to input department id.

Second, when you execute a SELECT in pl/sql, you have to provide a place to put the result.  That is done by adding the INTO clause.  Look it up.

Third, what is the 'empldeft.' qualification of your column names in the SELECT?  What is 'empldeft'?  Your table

Third, your 'CURSOR FOR LOOP' does not reference a cursor.  It references the name of the procedure itself.  There are two ways to doing a CURSOR FOR LOOP.  The first is to explicity define a cursor, then reference it:

```
create or replace procedure getempldept (ed_deptid IN employees.department_id%TYPE)
    is
    cursor c1 is 
            SELECT empldeft.ed_emplname,
                   empldeft.ed_deptid,
                   empldeft.ed_deptname
            FROM   employees,
                   departments
            WHERE  department_id=ed_deptid;
    
    begin
      for x in c1
      loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('Employename: '
        || empldeft.ed_emplname , ' departname:'
        ||empldeft.ed_deptid , 'departid :'
        || empldeft.ed_deptname );
      END LOOP;
    end;
```

But I prefer to put the query in the loop definition:

```
create or replace procedure getempldept (ed_deptid IN employees.department_id%TYPE)
is
begin
          for x in (SELECT empldeft.ed_emplname,
                       empldeft.ed_deptid,
                       empldeft.ed_deptname
                FROM   employees,
                       departments
                WHERE  department_id=ed_deptid)
          loop
            dbms_output.put_line ('Employename: '
            || empldeft.ed_emplname , ' departname:'
            ||empldeft.ed_deptid , 'departid :'
            || empldeft.ed_deptname );
          END LOOP;
end;
```

what is the 'empldeft.' qualification of your column names in the SELECT?  What is 'empldeft'?  Your table names are EMPLOYEES and DEPARTMENTS.

There  is no need of a COMMIT.  You haven't done any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETED *to* COMMIT.

You've have not JOIN criteria when selecting multiple tables.

In your output, you are mixing the lables for department name and department id.

Let's try again.  I don't know your tables, and you seem thorougly confused about what is comging from where, I'll use column names that align with the standard demo tables.

```
create or replace procedure getempldept (i_deptid IN employees.department_id%TYPE)
is
begin
  for x in (SELECT e.employee_name,
                   D.dept_name
                FROM   employees e
                join departments d on e.dept_id = d.department_id
             where d.dept_id = i_deptid)
          loop
            dbms_output.put_line ('Employename: '|| x.employee_name||
                                  ' departname: '|| x.dept_name ||
                                  ' dept_id   : '|| i_deptid
                                 );
          END LOOP;
end;
```